# Render attribute or null

Tags: reactjs, jsx

For Firefox (which is disabling a button on `disabled=""`) I need to not output the attribute, but having a hard time with **jsx**. Is wrong?

```
{(a && !b) ? null : "disabled"}
```

Guess it is - but how to articulate that?

Thanks so much! Time off and brain dead!

Comment: `disabled={!(a && !b)}`

Comment: But ff is keeping the button disabled. Works fine in chrome. FF isn't liking disabled=""

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yhpc5p this looks good in FF

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you run into this problem, if I add `disable={false}` to a button React doesn't even bother to add it to the button (probably it knows something about Firefox), but in general if you want to conditionally add an attribute do something like this:

```
let myProps={}
if(something)
{
    myProps.disabled = true;
}
return ( <input onClick={doSomethingUseful} {...myProps} /> );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a style as backup plan:

```
const disabledButton = {
  cursor: "default",
  pointerEvents: "none"
}

<button style={(a && !b) ? disabledButton : {} } disabled={!(a && !b)}>
```